# Regular neighborhood of a connected, compact, orientable surface with boundary in $S^3$

Tags: geometric-topology, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

Why a regular neighborhood of a connected, compact, orientable surface F with boundary in $S^3$ is a handlebody of genus 2g+n-1? (where g is a gunus of F, and n is the number of boundary components of F.)

(This is mentioned without proof in Lickokish's book "An Introduction to Knot Theory"( in the proof of Proposition 6.3.) .)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $F$ has a deformation retract $G \subset F$ which is a rose with $2g+n-1$ petals, and any regular neighborhood of $F$ is also a regular neighborhood of $G$, which is a handlebody of genus $2g+n-1$.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm inexperienced in geometric topology, and can't understand why a regular neighborhood of a rose is a handlebody. Could you tell me why or tell me any references?

Comment: The [wikipedia page for handle bodies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handlebody) contains a pretty clear picture in genus 3